# Can I use 2 foreign keys with same primary key on same table

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a mysql database with a table titled genre.

Users will be allowed to enter a main genre and a sub genre.

The genre database will be pre-populated with options provided by me. Example: 
HipHop
Country
R&B
Latin
ect.

Both genre and sub-genre will be foreign keys pointing back to the genre table's primary key. My question is if this is a valid way of writing my table, or is there a better solution?

The tables look like this:

**USERS**

id|username|email

**GENRE**

id|genre

**USERS-GENRE**

id|userId|genreId|subgenreId

Comment: It's called a self-join and yes, it is a valid way of doing it. However, if sub-genres are not genres they shouldn't necessarily be in the genrres table. Could cause confusion later on. Better to do a many to many relationship.

Comment: Yes, this is fine.

Comment: @VikingBlooded It's not a self-join. Self-join is when a table has a foreign key to another column in itself. For instance, an `Employee` table that has a `manager` field that points to another `Employee` row.

Comment: You are correct, I misread his setup.